# Docker postgres mounts volume to an existing container

Tags: postgresql, docker, volume, mount

I would like to share a solution that help us to mount a volume to an existing container.
The scenario is:
I have been run a container base on postgres image without create a volume, now the data is quite large. At this time, if I delete the container, the data will be totally deleted. So I tried to find the way to mount all existing data to a volume to prevent data loss.

What I've done:

- Create a volume:
  `docker volume create my-volume`
- Commit my existing container (that is create a new image from container’s changes):
  `docker commit <container-id> newimagename`
- Run new container with mount
  `docker run -ti -v my-volume:/data/postgres newimagename /bin/bash`
  /data/postgres is a path that store the data inside container
  After do that, all data in existing container will be mount to the host path, it be stored at /var/lib/docker/volumes/my-volume
  You can you the new container for your system that replace the old one, or you can recreate the old one with mount.
  If anyone has another solution, please share!

Comment: ...what's your question?  How is it related to programming?